# Android Emulator gets stuck (Using HAXM)

Tags: android-emulator

I recently read about the **HAXM** , followed the steps, for first few days emulator used to get started in less than minute but now it gets stuck at this point - as  shown below.. although it shows correct time & clock remains working . The worst part is all of the emulators I create show same problem .Any solution ?

[image: Android Emulator]

Answer (score 0):

You can try couple of things here

1. Check the RAM size allocated for Emulator. The best RAM size recommended is around 512MB for an Emulator. Make sure you have set the appropriate RAM size
2. Kill all your emulators, restart your machine and create fresh AVDs
3. Is this happening with the same application or different ones? a little bit detail on the application will help in suggesting more work around.

   a. If it is an OpenGL application choose use Host GPU on your AVD and also install the correct graphics driver on your host machine